# How to convert json string to geojson?

Tags: json, geojson, shapefile

I have a json string with fields from google maps api (direction service-coordinates,travel mode, etc). I want to format my json string to geojson in order to convert it after to shapefile. How can I do that?

An example of a json string I have:

```
{
    "travelMode": [
        [
            "WALKING"
        ],
        [
            "WALKING"
        ]
    ],
    "startLat": 48.1493978,
    "startLng": 11.56919229999994,
    "endLat": 48.1509212,
    "endLng": 11.564903700000059,
    "waypoints": [],
    "paths": [
        [
            [
                {
                    "k": 48.14940000000001,
                    "B": 11.56919
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.14954,
                    "B": 11.569280000000001
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.1497,
                    "B": 11.569360000000001
                }
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                {
                    "k": 48.1497,
                    "B": 11.569360000000001
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.14976,
                    "B": 11.569120000000002
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.14985,
                    "B": 11.56877
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.149860000000004,
                    "B": 11.56872
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.14992,
                    "B": 11.568510000000002
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.150130000000004,
                    "B": 11.56779
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.15019,
                    "B": 11.567580000000001
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.15021,
                    "B": 11.567530000000001
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.150400000000005,
                    "B": 11.56681
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.150760000000005,
                    "B": 11.56544
                },
                {
                    "k": 48.150920000000006,
                    "B": 11.564900000000002
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you may already know this if not please check out http://geojson.org/

Comment: This might be better as a comment on the question.